# Is "MAX_FILE_SIZE" always written in upper-case? Does it have to be?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

Why is the MAX_FILE_SIZE for an HTML `<input type="file">` always in uppercase?

All examples I've seen do this. Why?

Is this something historical / are there lots of examples on the web which doesn't use uppercase which I just didn't see?

Comment: You can always test if PHP supports lowercase name.

Comment: @yes123: huh... Where did that tag from?

Comment: @yes123: someone changed the tags

Comment: FYI: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=40387

Comment: Just to expand Steve-o comment. Browsers don't support this. PHP check the posted variable and removes the file from the $_FILES array if exceeding the the value. The user however will just have wasted the upload MBs. Users can also edit the value of the hidden input, so you can't rely on it. So it's rather useless.

Comment: I added the PHP tag because MAX_FILE_SIZE is a PHP-only thing. I'm not going to add it *again*, but it is a tag that this question should have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an HTML feature, but a PHP feature.

[The documentation explains](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) how PHP looks for a field named `MAX_FILE_SIZE` in form data, and uses its value for handling file uploads if applicable.

It's a matter of historical convention that constants are capitalised and, traditionally, a field like `MAX_FILE_SIZE` would be a constant in an application. Matters are complicated slightly because, as far as PHP is concerned, it's actually a variable (named `$_POST['MAX_FILE_SIZE']`) and isn't constant at all; still, if you take the web application *as a whole*, you could see how this convention might still apply.

It also sets the field name apart from any other fields that the user has in his/her form.

Note that, since [access to arrays by string key is case-sensitive](http://codepad.org/B0whVxBY), it makes sense to assume that PHP's search for this form field is also case-sensitive. So, if you were considering otherwise, *stick with the capitalisation*.

Answer (score 3):

Constant generally are always Uppercase. That's true for every language.

Comment: because it can't be anything else

Comment: How _can_ it be a constant? It's user-provided data.

Comment: its name it's a costant not the value

Comment: @yes123: Any variable's name is constant.

Comment: Also, "that's true for every language" is rather short-sighted. I can create a language in a few moments where constants are not uppercase. In fact, strictly speaking, I don't know of _any_ language that defines any case for names of constants.

Comment: @Tomalak: [Not in PHP, unfortunately](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

Comment: @You: The name of one, single variable is fixed. That you can define that fixed name initially through a variable expression is not relevant. You still cannot change it afterwards. (tldr: Don't mistake "constant" for "static". :D) "Variable variables" is an interesting misnomer.

Comment: @tomalak: your mind is not even a little flexible, you should start considering to open your horizons and to don't see everything black or white.

Comment: @yes123: Excuse me? I am very open-minded, thank you; but that doesn't magically make `MAX_FILE_SIZE` a constant, or your answer any less wrong.